# How do I show what command runs my Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse

I'm running a Spring Boot App with Eclispe and I'd like to know what command or script Eclipse is using to run it. When it starts it only shows the spring boot output.

I'd also like Eclipse to show how other projects are run not only spring boot. Maybe there's a setting to enable this or a log file somewhere that would show it.

**Console output:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.3.RELEASE)

2019-08-31 14:25:42.106  INFO 32045 --- [           main] be.heydari.seed.Application 
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog and find your Java Application in the list. There should be a 'Show Command Line' button near the bottom right of the dialog.

This button was added in Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9) (`sudo snap install eclipse --classic`). The eclipse snap package has Java IDE pre-installed. Older versions of Eclipse don't have a way to see the command line.
[image]

Comment: I don't see that option.

Comment: This feature is quite new. It was added in Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9)

Comment: I was running as a Spring Boot App which doesn't have that option. I ran as a Java Applicaiton and it shows and runs fine.